# How can I play music at more than 10 locations while controlling them all from one place?

Tags: audio, software, music, controller, control

I was tasked with finding a way to play music in more than 10 super markets, all are in different locations (which all of them are on the same network and being controlled from the HQ).
The question is what can I do to make it possible? to be able to control what is being played for all the stores at the same time without having to login to each store and playing something individually? is there a centralized way to do such thing?

Comment: What have you found so far? Why wasn't it acceptable?

Comment: I have found only music services, like companies that provide a radio service or can create you playlists for you depending on your type of work. and most of them don't operate at my country.
None of them had what I have in mind, which is a centralized way of managing the music or the broadcast being played at all the stores from a single location or a platform.

Comment: Look at Shoutcast. We don't know what country you're in or who operates there.

Comment: Iraq it is, the country I reside in. I have contacted Shoutcast and I'll see what they can provide, Thanks for the help <3